# Extension Method for Polly Policy

Tags: c#, polly, retry-logic

I am trying to find the best way to write an extension method for Polly Policy

I have the following

```
public static async Task<IPollyDto> RunAsync(this IPolicy dtoClass, Func<Task<IDto>> action)
{
    return
        await Policy
            .Handle<ApiException>(ex => ex.StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.RequestTimeout)
            .RetryAsync(3,
                async (exception, retryCount) => await Task.Delay(200))
            .ExecuteAsync(async () => await action.Invoke().ConfigureAwait(false))
            .ConfigureAwait(false);
}

public interface IPollyDto {}
public interface IPolicy {}
```

Then I call the code as follows

```
public class DtoTest : IPollyDto
{
}

public class TestA
{
    public static async Task<DtoTest> GetItem(string datasetName)
    {
        return await Task.Run(() => new DtoTest()) ;
    }
}

public class PollyTest : IPolicy
{
    public async Task<DtoTest> TestMe(string dataset)
    {
       return (DtoTest) await this.RunAsync(() => Task.Run(() => (IPollyDto) TestA.GetItem(dataset)));
    }
}
```

I get an error resolving types.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are missing `async-await` in your  `this.RunAsync(() => Task.Run(() => (IPollyDto) TestA.GetItem(dataset)))` call. Change it to:

```
this.RunAsync(() => Task.Run(async () => (IPollyDto)(await TestA.GetItem(dataset))));
```

Or just:

```
this.RunAsync(async () => (IPollyDto)(await TestA.GetItem(dataset)))
```

Comment: thanks Guru Stron, i get a compile time error and i need to change it to             return (DtoTest) await this.ExecutePollyAsync(async () => (IPollyDto) (await TestA.GetItem(dataset)));
 but still get the same error when executing

Comment: @MicroMan yes, the rest of your code was supposed to remain untouched.See [this](https://dotnetfiddle.net/TSRbOw) fiddle, I've changed `Func<Task<IDto>> action` to `Func<Task<IPollyDto>> action` in `RunAsync` cause `IDto` was not defined.